# Filter POIs that are close to a route

Tags: google-maps, openstreetmap, osrm

I have a list of Points-of-Interest (e.g. car rest areas).

The user selects the Starting Point and the Ending Point. 
This generates a route.

1. How can I programmatically filter the POIs that are close (e.g. 50 meters distance from the road) that route?
2. Can `Google Maps SDK` or `OSRM` offer this functionality?

Thank you,
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. You have to find the distance from one POI to the road.

In order to accomplish this, you have to store your road in a mathematical fashion:

- You can sample equidistant points of your road and store them in an array (more practical, less precise) and then calculate the distance of the POI from every point in the array, then save the minor result and repeat the whole process for every POIs.
- You can store a road in a function (more and more complex, but more precise). Now that you have this function, you can calculate same distance from your POI, take the minimum value and repeat for all POIs.

### 2. Google Distance Matrix can actually do this

With [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro) Api you can calculate distance till 2500 origins * destinations points.
The result will give you an array of rows, with each row corresponding

> to an origin, and each element within that row corresponds to a pairing of the origin with a destination value.

Example of a request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=32.777211,35.021250&destinations=32.778663,35.015757&key=YOURAPIKEY
```

This is very useful to your goal, because lets you specify more than one points of which calculates distance.

Comment: Thank you Alex. Is there a way to get the equidistant points of a calculated route? Distance Matrix adds a licensing factor to this problem.

Comment: It depends on how you calculate the route. Please, can you show me (or edit question) an example of your route data?

Comment: I use Google Maps SDK on Android to give start and end points. This "draws" the route. Can I have access to the distinct points of the route? Should I use another component (e.g. OSM data)?

Comment: In the response you should see a field, called polyline. Once you have it, you can decode it (with some extra code, try to google "polyline decode") in an array of points (that represents sampling points of the route)